# Determining rgb planes of a color image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

What is meant by red,green or blue plane of a color image?How do we generate the red plane?how is it different from the other planes?Please explain the logic behind generating these planes?

Comment: Depends on an indexed or truecolor image. What do you want to achieve and what color image exactly do you have? [How MATLAB Represents Pixel Colors](http://www.mathworks.de/company/newsletters/articles/how-matlab-represents-pixel-colors.html)

Comment: I want to know as to how is a red plane different from a blue plane or from a green plane of a color image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer:

Say you read a 480x640 color image, like so:

```
A = imread('image.jpg');
```

The matrix `A` has dimensions `480 x 640 x 3`. The third dimension are three `480 x 640` planes, or color channels:

```
red = A(:,:,1)
green = A(:,:,2)
blue = A(:,:,3)
```

Now you can go to the link @Trilarion gave in the comments and look at the portion about `Truecolor Images`.

Answer (score 6):

Every pixel in a normal colour image is made up of a red part, a green part and a blue part - hence `RGB image`. Typically there is one byte for the red part at each location in the image, one for green and one for blue. As there is a byte for each pixel location, the red can vary between 0 (zero) which means "no red" and 255 which means "full red". Likewise the green and blue. So an image where all the pixels are

```
Red=255, Green=0, Blue=0 will look very bright red
Red=0, Green=255, Blue=0 will look very green
```

and a pixel where R=G=B will look grey, and if R=G=B=16 it will be very dark grey, and if R=G=B=240 it will be very light/bright grey.

So, the "red plane" is merely an image that only shows the red part of each pixel, or how much red there is in each pixel.

Here is a rose:

[image]

and here is the red plane, and you can see that where the rose is very red, the red plane is very bright meaning there is lots of red.:

[image]

Here is the green plane (you can see the green leaf on the right is bright):

[image]

and the blue plane (you can see the blueish petals on the left are bright):

[image]

If you want to separate the color channels (planes), it is very easy in ImageMagick to get the red plane, for example:

```
convert rose: -channel red -separate red.jpg
```

ImageMagick is free and amazing - available [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Comment: won't the pixel where r=g=b,be white i.e very bright

Comment: moreover,is the superimposition of the 3 planes linear?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `linear`. All R, G, B components have the same range and are 1:1 superimposed.

Comment: by linear I meant that are the 3 matrices obtained from the 3 planes simply added to get the array of the rgb plane?

Comment: They are normally shifted to the correct position in the word and then ORed together.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your comment, you want to know how a CCD of a camera catch the chroma of each color.

Have a look to [color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space)

And maybe about [wavelength of colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum) (Look at the table of color frequency/wavelength for more informations)

And [camera CDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device) to understand how camera catch those wavelenght and create color channel of an image.